# Microsoft Graph API / Power Automate

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, power-automate

I am using Graph API to extract all the incidents and advisories from Microsoft but I encounter some issues, and I will be very happy if you can help me.

I am using the GET Method using the URL
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/issues but in the output, I can see that not all incidents are present, and I can see that there is present pagination in the output https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/admin/serviceAnnouncement/issues?$skip=100, can you guys help me how I should filter this to extract all the incidents from the API?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make multiple calls until the response provides no further link for you to retrieve further records.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

As is described in the above documentation ...

> You can retrieve the next page of results by sending the URL value of the @odata.nextLink property to Microsoft Graph.

As previously stated, once you have reached the last page, you will no longer have a `nextLink` value to retrieve the next page.